# unexpected threads in windows 8 app on exit

Tags: xaml, visual-c++, windows-8.1

1. Open Visual Studio 2013 in Windows 8.1
2. Create New project -> Visual C++ -> Windows Store -> Blank app (XAML)
3. Run (in Debug mode)
4. Press Close button ([X] button in the top right corner on the screen)

Behavior:

Visual Studio Environment waits for about 15 seconds and then it prints messages in the Debug output console:

> Thread 0x123c terminated with code 0 (0x0)
>
> Thread 0x223 terminated with code 0 (0x0)
>
> ...

You have to wait for about 15 seconds to see next message, and debugging does not stop until you finish it by pressing "stop debugging" in the Visual Studio. Then Visual Studio prints other 8-10 messages in Debug output, prints

> Program "[4388] App1.exe" terminated with code 0 (0x0).

and stops debugging.

Expected behavior:

Normal program finishing in 1-2 seconds without tons of thread terminations.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: So you closed the app, and you saw it terminate all threads successfully and exit with success. Why do you think there's a problem?

Comment: The xaml app is closed only if you push the button in the Visual Studio, otherwise it emits the threads infinitely (the time limit is 1-2 seconds as if you play with the MFC application).

Comment: Windows store apps are not like MFC, they effectively don't close, just go into sleep mode. That's part of the normal life cycle, so not unexpected although I grant you it's different from MFC.

Comment: [As it explains here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx) - *"When the user closes an app by pressing Alt+F4 or using the close gesture, the app is suspended for 10 seconds and then terminated"* - does that help explain things?